# what is the limit and behavior of this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading the book about measure theory of Terry Tao by my own, and I want to prove that: 
$$ | I| = \lim_{N \to \infty} \# \left( I \cap  \frac{Z}{N} \right)$$

where $I$ is an interval, $\#A$ denotes the cardinality of $A$, and $\frac{Z}{N}=\left\{\frac{n}{N}: n \in Z  \right\} $.

If I define  a sequence like: $a_{N}=\frac{1}{N}\#\left( I \cap  \frac{Z}{N} \right)$, what is its behavior?.

Comment: What is $I{}{}$?

Comment: sorry. $I$ is an interval.

Comment: you need $\frac{1}{N}$ in front of the count in the definition of the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I = [a,b]$ with $a<b$ reals (it does not matter if the endpoints are included or not as the argument below shows). Then for $N\in \mathbb{N}$ we have 
$$
\# \left( I \cap \frac{Z}{N} \right) = \#\{n \in \mathbb{Z}: a N \leq n \leq b N\} := a_N.
$$

Then 
$$
[bN] - [aN] \leq  a_N \leq [bN] - [aN] + 1 \tag{1}
$$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the integer part of a real number. For each $x\in \mathbb{R}$, in view of the definition of the integer part we have $xN - 1 < [xN] \leq xN$ and hence 
$$
x - \frac{1}{N} < \frac{[xN]}{N} \leq x ,
$$
which implies that $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \frac{[xN]}{N} = x$. Applying this on $(1)$ shows that $\frac{a_N}{N} \to b-a$ as $N \to \infty$.